# Replacing text on template from UI inputbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I have basically modified a UI that comes on the UI google documentation to adapt it to my needs. I have a panel that gets info from user, then it is supposed to replace some words in a template and at the end send an email. This is what I have written so far. Everything works great just the part where it makes the replace is not working which(var Time = setValue(e.parameter.userName) but I am not sure if is correct or I should use something different. I tried using var Time = emailTemplate.replace("TIME",e.parameter.userName)); but I get reference error, e is not defined and is not running. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 function onOpen() {
var subMenus = [{name:"test", functionName: "doGet"}];
           SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("texts", subMenus);}

    function doGet() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SP ID");
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('TITLE1');
  var grid = app.createGrid(10, 10);
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Time PST'));

   grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Time'));
  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Minutes have passed'));

  grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Minutes'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('Enter Name'));
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Name'));
  // Create a vertical panel..
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  // ...and add the grid to the panel
  panel.add(grid);


  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('b');
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  // Add the button to the panel and the panel to the application, then display the                      application app
    panel.add(button);
    app.add(panel);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
  }


  function b() {

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SP ID");
    var emailTemplate =                              SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange("A1").getValue() ;
    var address = "albdominguez25@gmail.com";
    var Time = setValue(e.parameter.Time);
    var emailSubject = "Subject";
    emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace("TIME",Time);  


    MailApp.sendEmail(address, emailSubject, emailTemplate);
    Browser.msgBox("Your Email has been sent!");


    // Clean up - get the UiInstance object, close it, and return
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.close();
    // The following line is REQUIRED for the widget to actually close.
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.show(app);
  }​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to change the text in the TextBox 'Time' when the button is clicked.

First, you need to set an id on the text box

```
function doGet(){
  ...
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Time').setid('Time');
  ...
}
```

Then, you need to use setText() on the TextBox to change the value

```
function b(e){ // Note the argument 'e'
  ...
  var Time = app.getElementById('Time').setText(e.parameter.Time);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right track, Srik's answer is correct, but it sounds like you don't need or want to do the second part. But you do need to `setID("Time")` on the TextBox in order to get the data in it usign `e.parameter.Time`.

And you should change

```
var Time = setValue(e.parameter.Time);
```

to

```
var Time = e.parameter.Time;
```

That should work for you, although I would have gone a completely different way, and used the HTMLService with a template file, and publish the script as a stand alone app.

Comment: As a complement to this correct answer, I'd suggest to avoid using the same var name for `emailTemplate` before and after the `.replace`... use for instance `var emailBody = emailTemplate.replace('Time',Time);` and also (as Srik said) don't forget the `e` as an argument to your handler function as this is the "event info" that holds all data from the `doGet` function

Comment: -Your answer is not "fully" right, you DON'T need to set an `ID` to a textBox to get its value (in fact I misread your answer in the first place, that's why I said it was correct, my brain added a "don't" that my eyes didn't see ;) ONLY the name is necessary for the `e.parameter`

Comment: Excellent! Yeah I got it to work guys.. thanks a lot for your help :) @Sergeinsas what exactly do you mean by this  "That should work for you, although I would have gone a completely different way, and used the HTMLService with a template file, and publish the script as a stand alone app" do you have any links where I can check this HTMLService thing?? Thank you!

Comment: @AlbertDominguez, straight from the horses mouth: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service